# Stop executing a pipeline transform while other pipeline transforms keep running

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a number of files in google storage which I have to write to multiple tables in BigQuery after applying a simple ParDo transform which I am trying to execute using a single pipeline. So basically I have a number of parallel unconnected sources and sinks running with a single pipeline in one dataflow job. 
In the Pardo transform, I have a condition which if it evaluates to true, then writing to the particular BigQuery table(transform) has to stop while writing to other BigQuery tables(other transforms) remain as usual.
[image]

In this image, there are 2 parallel sources and 2 parallel sinks, Because of some bad data in source for date 2014-08-01, the first transform failed. Once the 2014-08-01 transform failed, the 2014-08-02 tranform got cancelled. The 2014-08-02 transform had no bad data.

Is there a way to prevent the cancellation of the other transform?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Nothing should be written, or all of the elements already written should be written? Also, what kind of condition is this? Is it based on time? Properties of the elements? If the ParDo was being processed on many machines, would they all be able to see that this stop signal had been received? If an element arrives after the stop signal has been received with an earlier timestamp (late data), should it be emitted?

Comment: When a particular transform stops, nothing should be written in the sink of that transform while other transform continues execution.
The condition is based on the property of the elements. I will explain more in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in the Dataflow service, an entire pipeline will either succeed or fail, and any failure will cancel the rest of the pipeline.  There's no way to change this behavior; you need to run separate pipelines if you want to have them succeed or fail separately.

Note that operationally, you can run both pipelines from the same Java main program; just create two different Pipeline objects and invoke run() on them separately.